# How can I set the schema to use in Parse Server?

Tags: parse-server

I am develloping a app using Parse Server. As I am trying different providers, and modifying my schema regularly to try and test, I d like to know how I can set a schema on a freshly installed parse server.

For now, I m forced to also install parse dashboard, launch it, then use the UI to create the schema, or erase the mongoDB collection and recreate from parse dashboard, or let my app send the request and pray that every field get detected with the right type.

Is there a file I can modify to set multiples schema at once, with the fields and type? Or a command to just create the schema without sending data?

EDIT:

Just found out that the undocumented `.set`/`.put` method can add column from the code, instead of sending the whole object and praying, but still deduce the type from the data, and is as such still not suitable for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the schema are stored in the mongoDB collection assigned to parse. Pushing my documents, or editing them, in mongoDB reflected correctly in parse server.